# Constructor Error, prints out 'a' and then a triangle before crashing

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor, member

[image: The Error]

```
    QuBiEngine::QuBiEngine(ifstream& dnaFile)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(!dnaFile.eof()) //while the file isn't at its end
    {
        dna.push_back(""); //creates an element
        if(!dnaFile.good())//checks for failbits and other errors
        {
            dna[i] = "Not a valid sequence";
            i++;
            continue; 
        }
        getline(dnaFile, dna[i]);
        //checks to see if the character is valid ie: a, t, c, g
        for(int j=0; j<dna[i].length(); j++)
        {
            dna[i][j] = putchar(tolower(dna[i][j]));
            if((dna[i][j]!='a')||(dna[i][j]!='t')||(dna[i][j]!='c')||(dna[i][j]!='g'))
            {
                dna[i] = "Not a valid sequence";
                i++;
                break;
            }            
        }
        i++;        
    }
}
```

This takes each line in the dnaFile `ifstream` and puts it in a vector if it passes the tests, if it doesn't then it just puts the not valid thing in the vector.

Comment: You probably don't want to be using `!dnaFile.eof()`. Also, what kind of input are you using that gives that output?

Comment: @Xymostech Why do I not want to use `!dnaFile.eof()`? It's not even suppose to have an output, I commented out everything else past constructing my object.

Comment: Just using the return of `getline` usually works better, and is more reliable. Also, you are printing when you call the `putchar` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the `i++` in the second if statement makes it increment twice and thus overflow my vector.

Comment: And that's why i initially thought of continue there ;)

Comment: BTW in your if-condition you probably want `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might be missing `break;` in marked place:

```
    QuBiEngine::QuBiEngine(ifstream& dnaFile)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(!dnaFile.eof()) //while the file isn't at its end
    {
        dna.push_back(""); //creates an element
        if(!dnaFile.good())//checks for failbits and other errors
        {
            dna[i] = "Not a valid sequence";
            i++;
            continue; 
        }
        getline(dnaFile, dna[i]);
        bool bad = false;
        //checks to see if the character is valid ie: a, t, c, g
        for(int j=0; j<dna[i].length(); j++)
        {
            dna[i][j] = putchar(tolower(dna[i][j]));
            if((dna[i][j]!='a')||(dna[i][j]!='t')||(dna[i][j]!='c')||(dna[i][j]!='g'))
            {
                dna[i] = "Not a valid sequence";
                break;
            }            
        }
        i++;   
    }
}
```

Other than that: what is `dna` variable? Can you show us any declaration and initialization of it?

Other than that, if your `dna` is declared so that you will not get out of bounds (no checking)

Comment: Since there isn't anything after that if statement, I wouldn't need a `continue` there since it would just do nothing if that condition isnt met go on to the next iteration; if that condition is met I break out of the for loop.
`dna` is a vector, it's initialized in my class (header file) as a private variable
standard `vector<string> dna;`

Comment: My bad, i haven't noticed another loop - i meant `break` not `continue` - but I agree that it couldn't cause mentioned error. What is the data set that you are using? BTW in your if-condition you probably want `&&` instead of `||`